# calculate total experience in decimal from years, months, days field in codeigniter

Tags: php

A person has two experiences i.e one experience is about to 3 years and 11 months so we write it as 3.11 and second experience is about to two years and 4 month and it write as 2.4. when we add it result must be 6.3 because there are 12 months

I separated years, months and days field.
html

```
<input type="text" id="exp6_year" name="exp6_year" value=""/>
<select id="exp6_mon" name=">
 <option value="0.0">0</option>
 <option value="0.1">1</option>
 <option value="0.2">2</option>
 <option value="0.3">3</option>
 <option value="0.4">4</option>
 <option value="0.5">5</option>
 <option value="0.6">6</option>
 <option value="0.7">7</option>
 <option value="0.8">8</option>
 <option value="0.9">9</option>
 <option value="0.10">10</option>
 <option value="0.11">11</option>
```

```
<select id="exp6_day" name="exp6_day">
 <option value="0">0</option>
 <?php for ($a = 1; $a <= 29; $a++)
 {
   echo '<option value="0.0'.$a.'">'.$a.'</option>';
 }?>
```

Same as I have 2 more fields respectively exp7_year, exp7_mon, exp7_day, exp8_year,exp8_mon & exp8_day, and I want to store sum of total experience in one column
toal_exp.

[image: Example]

Comment: Note: for looping of your days, you should first check the days in the chosen month because each month have different no of days.

Comment: Also, for the values of your days, it should be `'0.'.($a / $noOfDaysinTheChosenMonth)` . Example if the total amount of days in the chosen month is 30 then dividing it with 30 will give you 1 month worth of value

Comment: To sum all values better to recalculate all data to days, then sum, then take years, month and days from tolat sum

Comment: am expecting total days 1-29 when its 30 day it will count as month.

Comment: am not taking 31st day or leap year

Comment: What does this have to do with sql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

I explode the strings to arrays and use modulo calculation to calculate the months.

```
$a = "3.11"; 
$b = "2.9"; 
$c = "3.10"; 
$d = "1.11";
$arr1 = explode(".", $a);
$arr2 = explode(".", $b);
$arr3 = explode(".", $c);
$arr4 = explode(".", $d);

$y = $arr1[0] + $arr2[0] + $arr3[0]  + $arr4[0]; // calculate years
If($arr1[1] + $arr2[1] + $arr3[1] + $arr4[1] >=12) $y += floor(($arr1[1] + $arr2[1] + $arr3[1] + $arr4[1])/12); // add years if months is more than 11 
$m = ($arr1[1] + $arr2[1] + $arr3[1] + $arr4[1])%12; // modulo calculate months

Echo $y . " " . $m;
```

https://3v4l.org/Ell2S

Comment: $a = "3.11";
$b = "2.9";
$c = "3.10";
$d = "1.11":

If($arr1[1] + $arr2[1] + $arr3[1] + $arr4[1] >=12) $y++;  ans(41)
so how many years add. bcoz it doing only one increment

Comment: That was not part of your question

Comment: i have 5 experiences field

Comment: Updated to suit your scenario in comments above.

Comment: i just pick your idea and apply check to condition, and your updated answer give me a dynamic approach...

Comment: Yes, but seriously are you calculating experience in days? What kind of experience is that? But yes, you can use the same method for days. You just need to decide if it's 30 or 31 days in a month. Then add the "overflowing months" to for example $arr1[1].